# How to integrate parallax effect in the webstite

Tags: reactjs, parallax

This is the website link: [Website](https://moonshot.ch/why-private-markets/)
Anyone know how to add this type of parallax effect in react website.

I have tried with react scroll parallax library but not able to make it

Comment: that is not normal parallax effect ,this is an images sequence played based on your scroll inside the specific section

Comment: They are using the [greensock library](https://greensock.com/gsap/). Your question as it stands is too vague to answer

Comment: @Kodr.F do you know how to add this

Comment: @KaifAyazKhan just take frames from the video you want to add , play and pause the video then take screenshot until u have 5 or 8 images of the scene , then add them above each other inside the div , then use javascript when user scroll  into the section get the percentage and calculate it based on how you would like to show the effect for example ( start of section , to mid of section ) the effect will play from 0% to 100% , and last you show and hide the frames (images) based on the percentage .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect is called images sequence, i will do my best to explain it for you with demo code .

**Use high resolution and low sized images**
the images should has very low size for example each image is 12kb or up to 34kb you should consider the 3rd party countries which has low internet speed .

**Add the images inside the container ( section container )**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/t57meexkb/horse_1.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/i86apnasr/horse_2.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6kc8v3lnv/horse_3.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/w4ej1j71n/horse_4.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/ddclrdch7/horse_5.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/nbxkdulwr/horse_6.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/phrv8cpd7/horse_7.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/n1un88wob/horse_8.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/9yz0oz6gb/horse_9.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/6gn0sl5kb/horse_10.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/vnxwsu8ob/horse_11.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/bhuetyd0r/horse_12.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/imc82zka3/horse_13.png" class="animated" />
    <img src="http://s23.postimage.org/auvi4fg4r/horse_14.png" class="animated" />
</div>
<div style="display: block; height: 2000px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

and then use javascript or jQuery to calculate the scroll inside the page or the desired section to play the sequence based on scroll percentage .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pictureCount = $('#container img').length;
    var scrollResolution = 50;

    animateHorse();
    
    function animateHorse() {
        var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        var imageIndex = Math.round(currentScrollPosition / scrollResolution);
        
        if (imageIndex >= pictureCount) {
            imageIndex = pictureCount - 1; // Select last image
        }
        
        $("#container img").hide();
        $("#container img").eq(imageIndex).show();
    }
    
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        animateHorse();
    });
});
```

a little CSS touches :

```
@import "compass/css3";

#container {
  position: fixed;
}

.animated {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

here is full working code :

https://codepen.io/nowmad/pen/NWLzrM

Comment: And one more thing can we add content on the top of container section

Comment: if you mean to add text or images or any content above the section or container yes you can , you need to make the layer above the container absolute , check this link for more info about it , the parent ( section)  is  relative , and the content is ( absolute ) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp